# Setting up Window tester pro linux. SWT error

Tags: linux, junit, eclipse-plugin, swt, window-tester

High, I have set up Google Window Tester on Open Suse Linux x64 distro and I get this error when I run the my Junit plugin test. Its RCP plugin application.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create widget reference for instance of org.eclipse.swt.custom.CBanner
   WindowTester: 201207141338 - linux,gtk,x86_64
 at com.windowtester.runtime.internal.factory.WTRuntimeManager.createReference(WTRuntimeManager.java:105)
 at com.windowtester.runtime.internal.factory.WTRuntimeManager.asReference(WTRuntimeManager.java:46)
 at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.widgets.SWTWidgetReference.forWidget(SWTWidgetReference.java:325)
 at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.widgets.SWTWidgetReference.asControlReferences(SWTWidgetReference.java:244)
 at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.widgets.CompositeReference$1.call(CompositeReference.java:34)
 at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.widgets.CompositeReference$1.call(CompositeReference.java:1)
 at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.widgets.SWTUIExecutor.execute(SWTUIExecutor.java:142)
 at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.widgets.SWTUIExecutor.run(SWTUIExecutor.java:97)
 ... 68 more
```

It seems to be a problem with the window tester runtime, any body ever tried to do this with Google window tester and got the same results?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WindowTester does not support Linux x86_64 platforms yet.